# Dagger 2 Android Subcomponents override

Tags: android, android-testing, dagger-2, android-espresso

if I create a subcomponent that I want to use in a specific feature with dagger lets say:

```
@TransactionsActivityScope
@Subcomponent(modules = {TransactionsModule.class})
public interface TransactionsComponent {

    TransactionsManager provideTransactionsManager();

    void inject(TransactionsFragment transactionsFragment);

    void inject(TransactionsFilterActivity transactionsFilterActivity);
}
```

I add it in the main app component with a plus:

```
TransactionComponent plusTransactionSubcomponent(TransactionModule transactionModule);
```

and use it in the fragment:
public class TransactionsFragment {
..
..
..

```
 @Override
    protected void setupGraph(DaggerAppGraph graph) {
        graph.plusTransactionsSubcomponent(new TransactionModule()).inject(this);
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to override this subcomponent in Espresso tests.
For components and component dependencies it is straight forward where you just write a TestAppComponent that extends the "original" component and punch the MockModules in it, but how to do this cleanly with Subcomponents?

I also took a look at the Dagger AndroidInjector.inject(this); solution for components and activity components would be similar but I see no way to do it cleanly for subcomponents and fragments.
I believe it would be suboptimal to write methods and overrides the Activity/Fragments component setters and do the overrides there.
Am I missing something?

Comment: do you find a good solution ?

Answer (score 3):

This was easy on the original Dagger, but not using Dagger 2. However, here is the solution: create a mocked **flavor** and a mocked module with exactly the same classname, filename and location. Now run your ui tests using the mocked flavor.

You can see in my [test project](https://github.com/Frank1234/FireBaseTest) how it is done.

- I use the real module in my app. Located at src/prod/.../[ContentRepositoryModule.java](https://github.com/Frank1234/FireBaseTest/blob/master/app/src/prod/java/com/ironflowers/firebasetest/data/repo/ContentRepositoryModule.java)
- I use a mocked module when testing: Located at src/mock/.../[ContentRepositoryModule.java](https://github.com/Frank1234/FireBaseTest/blob/master/app/src/mock/java/com/ironflowers/firebasetest/data/repo/ContentRepositoryModule.java)

My mocked module then references the FakeContentRepository, just as you were planning to do.

In the build.gradle:

```
flavorDimensions "api", "mode"
productFlavors {
   dev21 {
       // min 21 has faster build times, also with instant build
       minSdkVersion 21
       dimension "api"
   }
   dev16 {
        minSdkVersion 16
        dimension "api"
   }
   mock {
        dimension "mode"
   }
   prod {
        minSdkVersion 16
        dimension "mode"
   }
}


// remove mockRelease:
android.variantFilter { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.name == 'release'
            && variant.getFlavors().get(1).name == 'mock') {
        variant.setIgnore(true);
    }
}
```

So again: [this test project](https://github.com/Frank1234/FireBaseTest) shows it all.

Comment: Yes this is one option but I see it as suboptimal I would prefer to have test code only in androidTest sofar I've managed to do it with overriding the components in test activity but for subcomponents I still dont have any clean code inspiration

Comment: Let me know if you find an easier solution. The main/only drawback from the above approach is the management of the folders.

Answer (score 0):

In our app we use additional wrapper to manage subcomponents scope with name `ComponentStorage`. Our `Application` create this object, `TestApplication` overrides it and return `TestComponentStorage`. So we can easily override method `plusTransactionSubcomponent` and return component with mocked module.

```
public class ComponentStorage {
    protected TransactionComponent transactionComponent;
    protected AppGraph graph;

    public ComponentStorage() {
        graph = buildGraph();
    }

    public TransactionComponent plusTransactionSubcomponent(TransactionModule transactionModule) {
        if(transactionComponent == null) {
            transactionComponent = graph.plusTransactionsSubcomponent(new TransactionModule());
        }
        return transactionComponent;
    }

    public AppGraph buildGraph() {
        return DaggerAppGraph.create();
    }

    // to manage scope manually
    public void clearTransactionSubcomponent() {
        transactionComponent = null;
    }
}


public class TestComponentStorage extends ComponentStorage{

    @Override
    public TransactionComponent plusTransactionSubcomponent(TransactionModule transactionModule) {
        if(transactionComponent == null) {
                                                                        // mocked module
            transactionComponent = graph.plusTransactionsSubcomponent(new TestTransactionModule());
        }
        return transactionComponent;
    }
}
```

In client code you will use it  `componentStorage.plusTransactionsSubcomponent(new TransactionModule()).inject(this)`

If you need full code, leave comment I will create gist for this.